# Correcting plane parameters with the fixed azimuth angles

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d, geometry

NOTE: first, i should say that I posted this in here as many mathematicians are experts in C++ so, I believe by posting my problem in this forum, it helps me to get comments from  such persons.

> I am trying to reconstruct specific 3d objects such as *cubes,
>   pyramids* and so on. For this, i am using point cloud data and then
>   fitting planar surfaces for the segmented point patches. Planes are
>   obtained by doing Least sqaure adjustments. Then my objective is to
>   intersect neighbouring planes and then to get intersection lines (line
>   segments). Then from those lines, i wish to make a something like
>   wireframe model.
>
> *But, when i get all the normal vectors (n1, ..n4 in this object) and then if i project them onto XY plane and calculated the azimuths of
>   each plane, then they are not exactly changing by 90 degree but 92,
>   87….. I guess because of this plane rotation, the
>   intersection lines do not meet to one single pyramid top.*

So, as i am looking for an accurate pyramid model, i think i should **first adjust these planes in a way to having their azimuths exactly in 90 degree differences with adjacent plane**. After that, i think i should **intersect them**, *this will allow me to reconstruct accurate and regular shape objects*.

please refer following sample images
[image]

> **Now, i want to know, how should i update my plane parameters in a way
>   to reside their azimuth differences exactly in 90 degrees with other
>   planes. In this case, should i change both (a, b, c) and d. where the
>   plane equation is ax+by+cz+d=0.**

**Could you please give me equations and way to do this. thank you.**

Comment: Your question is explicitly not programming related.  You ask for equations on a programming Q&A site.  Off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its not programming-related. Try to post your question in another SE site, like http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @High Performance Mark: let me know the url of that site, thanks

Comment: Do you want the differences in azimuth to be 90 degrees, or do you want the planes to meet in a point? I ask now in order to avert a lot of follow-up questions.

Comment: @Beta: many many thanks for asking this. Basically I need to update the planes in a way to reside them with 90 azimuth difference with their adjacent planes not to meet them in a one point.

Comment: @Beta: I hope you could show me the way to solve this. thank you again.

Comment: @Beta: looking forward to hearing from you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane that contains a face of the solid is defined by ax+by+cz+d=0, which has a normal vector (a, b, c). We can ignore the z-component (c), but we must rotate the component in the x-y plane, (a, b), so that it is perpendicular to that of the neighboring faces.

Consider face 1 and face 2. Face 1 has normal **n<sub>1</sub>** = (a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>), and the projection of **n<sub>1</sub>** into the x-y plane is (a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>), which we can call **k<sub>1</sub>**. Likewise, **k<sub>2</sub>** = (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>).

We want to rotate **k<sub>2</sub>** to **k'<sub>2</sub>**, so that **k'<sub>2</sub>** has the *magnitude* of **k<sub>2</sub>**, but a *direction* 90 degrees from **k<sub>1</sub>**. So we'll take **k<sub>1</sub>**, rotate it 90 degrees (clockwise), then scale it:

**k'<sub>2</sub>** = (b<sub>1</sub>, -a<sub>1</sub>) sqrt(a<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>+b<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>)/sqrt(a<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+b<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>)

Comment: many thanks. to clarify, if I ask 3 things, (1.) what is the meaning of scalling. does it doing normalization? then, the new normal vector (k'2, c2) or something else? (2.) does this rotation still fit the points refering to the original plane? (3.) do you think after doing ratation, if i get intersection lines, then will they meet a single point because i feel it should be so in theoratically.

Comment: @gnp: (1) scaling means changing the size of something without changing its other characteristics like shape or direction, so yes, the new normal vector is (**k'2**, c), (2) It will fit some of them; that's what happens if you rotate a plane. If it fits all of them, then you have done nothing. (3) Probably not; you must adjust the d values. I did not address this because you said in a comment that it was not important.

Comment: thank you again. now some of my doubts are clear. so i would like to ask, wouldn't it be possible to update your answer by combining both issues. I mean, azimuth should be 90 or 180 degree and when taking intersection lines, all should be passing through a single point. (note: some other objects do have 180 azimuth difference with opposite neighbors, i want to use this case as well, then how the equation would change).

Comment: for the simplicity i am writing the question again as; is it possible to rectify both conditions. that is, azimuth should have 0, 90 or 180 differences and plane intersections are meeting at a one vertex.